# ActiveMQ: How to create subscriber for ActiveMQ.Advisory.Connection topic

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I am writing the alerts for **ActiveMQ version 5.4.3** for different event like client connected or disconnected. But I am not able to proceed and not able to create the subscriber for `ActiveMQ.Advisory.Connection` topic it is throwing exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.jms.JMSException: Cannot create a durable subscription for an advisory Topic
```

Any help in this would be appreciated.

Thanks
Jay

Answer (score 0):

You aren't allowed to create durable subscriptions for Advisory topics, exactly what the exception is telling you.  Just create a normal subscription and you won't get the error.